# How to change the background color on hover using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div>
  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#nav li a").hover(  
        function () { $(this).parent('ul').parent('li').find('a.active').css('background-color', 'Red'); }
      );
    });
  </script>
</div>
```

I am simply trying to change the background-colour of the menu item with a class name 'active'   when the user hovers over any other item.

Answer (score 3):

Just try this:

```
$(this)
      .parent()  // jump to li
      .parent()  // jump to ul
      .find('li a.active')  // find a.active
      .css('background-color', 'Red'); // apply css
```

But I think you can simply done with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nav li a").hover(function() {
        $('li a.active').css('background-color', 'Red');
    }, function() {
        // if you want to remove background
        // on mouse out then uncomment below line
        //$('li a.active').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    })
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yQxG9/17/)**

Comment: this is very close to what I am trying to do except I do not want to changethe background of the item that I am hovering but the item that has the class 'active'. So if I hover over 'contact', home will get a red background.

Answer (score 1):

here's a way to do it with .hover()

http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/ePDZH/

i added the code to handle hoverOut as well, since i assume you only wanted to show a red background when the user is over the link.  edit the demo any way you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `UL` is not parent of `<a>`. Use `parents()` or `closest()`. The immediate parent is an `LI`

http://api.jquery.com/parents/

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: 'Red' with caps is likely problem. ALso , there was no mention of what you want done after the hover finishes. As your code is now, it will never change back. Using class change is most common way to do this, it's easier to reset. codeparadox has editied his version about 15 times, he'll find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already scoping this functionality to the #nav div you can simplify everything by scoping your search for the .active anchor tag to that container.

```
// cache the jquery object
var $navDiv = $("#nav");

$("#nav li a").hover( function () {
    $navDiv.find("a.active").css("background-color", "red");
});
```

This will set the background color once you hover over any of the menu items, but when your mouse leaves the menu items (no longer hovering) the background will remain red. I would recommend toggling a class name on the .active anchor tag inside of the hover handler function.

```
//cache the jquery object
var $navDiv = $("#navDiv");

$("#nav li a").hover(function (){
    $navDiv.find("a.active").toggleClass("redBackground");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to add a class of `over` to `#nav` while hovering child `a` elements, then styling with CSS accordingly.

**JavaScript:** (requires jQuery)

```
(function($){

  $nav = $("#nav");
  $nav.on("mouseenter", "a", function(){
    $nav.toggleClass("over");
  }).on("mouseleave", "a", function(){
    $nav.toggleClass("over");
  });

})(jQuery);
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/m8jQv/1](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/m8jQv/1/)**